# Cannot persist detached object

Tags: java, postgresql, netbeans

i'm working with a java enterprise application that connects to a postresql database, and in the log file appears this error

```
javax.ejb.EJBException
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:3894)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:3794)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:3596)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1379)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1316)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:205)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:127)
at $Proxy120.create(Unknown Source)
at com.mirodinero.web.servlets.setMisDatos.processRequest(setMisDatos.java:111)
at com.mirodinero.web.servlets.setMisDatos.doGet(setMisDatos.java:140)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:315)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096)
at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:288)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:647)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:579)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:831)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:265)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106)
```

Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: 
Exception Description: Cannot persist detached object [com.mirodinero.entidad.DatosUsuario[idUsuario=Miguel LLorente]]. 
Class> com.mirodinero.entidad.DatosUsuario Primary Key> [Miguel LLorente]
    at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.base.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.util.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:440)
    at com.mirodinero.sesionBean.DatosUsuarioFacade.create(DatosUsuarioFacade.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1011)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityUtil.invoke(SecurityUtil.java:175)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeTargetBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:2920)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4011)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:197)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: Exception [TOPLINK-7231] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.1 (Build b60e-fcs (12/23/2008))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot persist detached object [com.mirodinero.entidad.DatosUsuario[idUsuario=Miguel LLorente]]. 
Class> com.mirodinero.entidad.DatosUsuario Primary Key> [Miguel LLorente]
    at oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ValidationException.cannotPersistExistingObject(ValidationException.java:2171)
    at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3257)
    at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.base.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:432)
    at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3226)
    at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.base.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:221)
    ... 44 more

and this:

```
javax.persistence.NoResultException: getSingleResult() did not retrieve any entities.
at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.EJBQueryImpl.throwNoResultException(EJBQueryImpl.java:274)
at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.base.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:513)
at com.mirodinero.sesionBean.DatosUsuarioFacade.findById(DatosUsuarioFacade.java:57)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor560.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1011)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityUtil.invoke(SecurityUtil.java:175)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeTargetBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:2920)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4011)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:197)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:127)
at $Proxy120.findById(Unknown Source)
at com.mirodinero.web.servlets.setMisDatos.processRequest(setMisDatos.java:96)
at com.mirodinero.web.servlets.setMisDatos.doGet(setMisDatos.java:140)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:315)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096)
at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:288)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:647)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:579)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:831)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:265)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106)
```

so i went to check the file where the error appears and the code looks like this:

```
public DatosUsuario findById(String id) {
    DatosUsuario du = null;
    try {
        du = (DatosUsuario) em.createNamedQuery("DatosUsuario.findByIdUsuario").setParameter("idUsuario", id).getSingleResult();
    } catch (Exception nre) {
        log.error("No existe el usuario: " + id + ", ex: ", nre);
    } finally {
        log.debug("du: " + du);
        return du;
    }
}
```

does anybody know where the error is? because in my webpage it looks like it saves the data 2 out of 3 times.

yes, actually the EntityExistExpection is given here:

```
public void create(DatosUsuario datosUsuario) {
    em.persist(datosUsuario);  // in this line
}

public void edit(DatosUsuario datosUsuario) {
    em.merge(datosUsuario);
}

public void remove(DatosUsuario datosUsuario) {
    em.remove(em.merge(datosUsuario));
}
```

but i guess it is needed to create the new user, right? or should it check if the user exist and then just edit the data? how can it be done?

Comment: You're showing us the code where you try to retrieve the detached object, which was never persisted, so you're getting a `NoResultException`.  We need to see `com.mirodinero.sesionBean.DatosUsuarioFacade.create` to figure out why the entity is being detached in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EntityExistsException is likely thrown because you need to do a em.merge() instead of em.persist().

You should create a save() method to be invoked by your client when the entity is not new and needs to be saved.

```
public void save(DatosUsuario datosUsuario) {
    em.merge(datosUsuario);
}
```

Alternatively, you can keep the create() method and check if the entity has been persisted yet.  Entities with an @Id and @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) will have the ID only when persisted.  So something like this could work:

```
public void createOrSave(DatosUsuario datosUsuario) {
    if (datosUsuario.getId() == null){
        em.persist(datosUsuario);
    }
    else{
        em.merge(datosUsuario);
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer at all.  This is a comment.  Who upvotes an answer that just says "Give me more information"?

Comment: Good point, I'll use the comments feature more.  Answer improved.

Comment: actually i already had the save() function, but didn't copied it. i even managed to write a code very similar to yours, but without .getID in the if condition... still don't know if it works perfectly, have to test it on new users to check if it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first exception is caused by an object being detached which can have several reasons. Like it was part of a transaction that has ended or it was part of a context that was closed. When you want to use it in a new transaction/context you need to call merge on your entity manager.

The last exception you posted is caused by passing an id to your findById function for which no object exists in the database. Behaviour of getSingleResult() is to throw an exception if there is not exactly one result.